# how to use ApplicationEventPublisher in spring integration with annotation?

Tags: events, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and I have to do some event based processing ? can anyone tell me how to use ApplicationEventPublisher. sample will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For publishing Spring Application events Spring Integration provides `ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler` component. This is one-way, just send producer and should be configured together with the `@ServiceActivator` annotations:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendEventChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler eventProducer() {
   return new ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler();
}
```

Also see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/applicationevent.html.